# Get parts of a NSURL in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

I have an NSString with the value of

```
http://digg.com/news/business/24hr
```

How can I get everything before the 3rd level?

```
http://digg.com/news/
```

Answer (score 437, accepted):

This isn't exactly the third level, mind you. An URL is split like that way:

- the protocol or scheme (here, `http`)
- the `://` delimiter
- the username and the password (here there isn't any, but it could be `username:password@hostname`)
- the host name (here, `digg.com`)
- the port (that would be `:80` after the domain name for instance)
- the path (here, `/news/business/24hr`)
- the parameter string (anything that follows a semicolon)
- the query string (that would be if you had GET parameters like `?foo=bar&baz=frob`)
- the fragment (that would be if you had an anchor in the link, like `#foobar`).

A "fully-featured" URL would look like this:

```
http://foobar:nicate@example.com:8080/some/path/file.html;params-here?foo=bar#baz
```

`NSURL` has a wide range of accessors. You may check them in the documentation for the [`NSURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, section *Accessing the Parts of the URL*. For quick reference:

- `-[NSURL scheme]` = http
- `-[NSURL resourceSpecifier]` = (everything from // to the end of the URL)
- `-[NSURL user]` = foobar
- `-[NSURL password]` = nicate
- `-[NSURL host]` = example.com
- `-[NSURL port]` = 8080
- `-[NSURL path]` = /some/path/file.html
- `-[NSURL pathComponents]` = @["/", "some", "path", "file.html"] (note that the initial / is part of it)
- `-[NSURL lastPathComponent]` = file.html
- `-[NSURL pathExtension]` = html
- `-[NSURL parameterString]` = params-here
- `-[NSURL query]` = foo=bar
- `-[NSURL fragment]` = baz

What you'll want, though, is something like that:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://digg.com/news/business/24hr"];
NSString* reducedUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"%@://%@/%@",
    url.scheme,
    url.host,
    url.pathComponents[1]];
```

For your example URL, what you seem to want is the protocol, the host and the first path component. (The element at index 0 in the array returned by `-[NSString pathComponents]` is simply "/", so you'll want the element at index 1. The other slashes are discarded.)

Comment: for anyone reading this: you need to get `[url.pathComponents objectAtIndex:1]` instead of index `0`, because the slashes are actually elements of the array, causing the code in this answer to output `http://digg.com//`

Comment: @Dima, good catch. However, only the first slash is considered a path component, the others are discarded. I'm not sure why, though.

Comment: Are we missing the filename from the bullet point list?  In this example, `file.html` isn't listed in the bullet points--I see we're jumping from the path to the query string...

Comment: @Brett, the file name is not a "section" of the URL itself, that's why I didn't list it–it's just part of the "file path"–but if you're interested, you can access it with `lastPathComponent`.

Comment: What would be the best approach to get a subdomain out of the above example e.g. the 'mobile' subdomain - http://mobile.digg.com/

Comment: @Ríomhaire, string manipulations are your best bet. (split, substring, the choice is yours)

Comment: digg.com? how old is this post! ;-)

Answer (score 7):

[image: Using Playground , language swift, I got this !]
Playground provides an interactive way of seeing this in action. I hope you can enjoy doing the same, a fun way to learn NSURL an important topic in iOS.