# Parsing NSURL in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSTextView control that could potentially have links in it. How do I get the full url of the link?

Here is what I have so far

```
-(BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)aTextView clickedOnLink:(id)aLink atIndex:(NSUInteger)charIndex 
 {
     NSURL *htmlURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:[aLink pathComponents]];
 }
```

This gives me a URL that begins with file://localhost ... How do I get rid of that portion of the URL?

Comment: it may be similar to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692947/get-parts-of-a-nsurl-in-objective-c-for-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/myweb/index.html"];
NSString* reducedUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"%@://%@",
    url.scheme,
    [url.pathComponents objectAtIndex:1]];
```