# How to extract and remove scheme name from NSURL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring, nsurl

What is proper way to extract and remove scheme name and `://` from a `NSURL`?

For example:

```
 note://Hello  ->  @"Hello"
 calc://3+4/5  ->  @"3+4/5"
```

so

```
NSString *scheme = @"note://";
NSString *path   = @"Hello";
```

for later use in:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:scheme object:path];
```

Comment: NSString *str = [urURL absoluteString];
NSString *string = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":// " withString:@""]
//try this

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/joeldev/JLRoutes/blob/master/JLRoutes/JLRoutes.m#L82).  It parses the entire URL scheme, but you get the gist of it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can look at it like this *(mostly untested code, but you get the idea)*:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSLog(@"url: %@", url);
    NSLog(@"scheme: %@", [url scheme]);
    NSLog(@"query: %@", [url query]);
    NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]);
    NSLog(@"path: %@", [url path]);

    NSDictionary * dict = [self parseQueryString:[url query]];
    NSLog(@"query dict: %@", dict);
}
```

So you can do this:

```
NSString * strNoURLScheme = 
 [strMyURLWithScheme stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[url scheme] withString:@""];

NSLog(@"URL without scheme: %@", strNoURLScheme);
```

parseQueryString

```
- (NSDictionary *)parseQueryString:(NSString *)query
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:6] autorelease];
    NSArray *pairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

    for (NSString *pair in pairs) {
        NSArray *elements = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        NSString *key = [[elements objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *val = [[elements objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];        
        [dict setObject:val forKey:key];
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

My inclination is to roll your own string searching for this:

```
NSRange dividerRange = [urlString rangeOfString:@"://"];
NSUInteger divide = NSMaxRange(dividerRange);
NSString *scheme = [urlString substringToIndex:divide];
NSString *path = [urlString substringFromIndex:divide];
```

This does what you've asked for in quite a literal fashion, dividing the URL in half around its scheme. For more advanced handling, you'll have to provide more details.

Answer (score 5):

just use the NSURL's API named: `resourceSpecifier` :)

and remove the two slashes from the beginning of the string:

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://some.url.com/path];`

`url.resourceSpecifier` will result in: `//some.url.com/path`

Comment: **This** is the correct answer. From TFM: "Any URL is composed of these two basic pieces.  The full URL would be the concatenation of [myURL scheme], ':', [myURL resourceSpecifier]"

Answer (score 1):

Remember, don't fight the frameworks especially when it comes to NSURL. This SO answer has a good breakdown of its abilities. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3693009/142358

NSURL's [scheme](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/path) and [path](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/path) properties are exactly what you want which (assuming the rest of your URL looks like a path) leaves you with this:

```
NSString *schemeWithDelimiter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://",[myURL scheme]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: schemeWithDelimiter object:[myURL path];
```

No string searching needed!

Answer (score 1):

Swift5, URL extension:

```
var resourceSpecifier: String {
    get {
        let nrl : NSURL = self as NSURL
        return nrl.resourceSpecifier ?? self.absoluteString
    }
}
var simpleSpecifier: String {
    get {
        let str = self.resourceSpecifier
        return str[2..<str.count]
    }
}
```