# How to strip part of an NSString after the first instance of a character?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I would like to strip part of an `NSString`.

in the following string I would like to just grab the digits before the "/sampletext1/sampletext2/sampletext3"

```
1464/sampletext1/sampletext2/sampletext3
```

I have already stripped out the web address before the digits, but can't figure out the rest. Sometimes the digits could be 3 or 4 or 5 digits long.

thanks

Comment: Are you dealing with a URL?  If so, you can convert to an NSURL and extract the various parts: path, host, port, query string, etc.

Comment: Otherwise, regular expressions are a good approach `@"^\\d+"`.

Comment: I ended up using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692947/get-parts-of-a-nsurl-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that you extracted a web address from the front, so I'm guessing you're dealing with either something like `http://localhost:12345/a/b/c` or `http://localhost/12345/a/b/c`.

In either case, you can convert your string to an NSURL and take advantage of its built-in features:

```
// Port
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:12345/a/b/c"];
NSUInteger port = URL.port.integerValue;

// Path component
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/12345/a/b/c"];
NSString *number = URL.pathComponents[1];
```

Answer (score 6):

Get the index of the first `/` character then get the substring up to that location.

```
NSString *stuff = @"1464/sampletext1/sampletext2/sampletext3";
NSString *digits;
NSRange slashRange = [stuff rangeOfString:@"/"];
if (slashRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    digits = [stuff substringToIndex:slashRange.location];
} else {
    digits = stuff;
}
```

Comment: thanks. any idea why I would get an "initializing 'NSRange *' (aka struct _NSRange) with an incompatible type NSRange?

Comment: Sorry, typo - don't use a pointer with the `slashRange` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *test = @"1464/sampletext1/sampletext2/sampletext3";
NSRegularExpression *aRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^\\d+"
                                                                        options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                          error:&error];

NSRange aRangeOfFirstMatch = [aRegex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:test options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [test length])];

if (aRangeOfFirstMatch.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSString *matchedString = [test substringWithRange:aRangeOfFirstMatch];
    NSLog(@"matchedString = %@", matchedString);
}
```