# Extracting values from the url in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

my url is `https://photos.googleapis.com/data/upload/resumable/media/create-session/feed/api/user/111066158452258/albumid/60281009241807`
i want to extract the value of `user` & `albumid`, i had tried to extract with different methods which i found in stack overflow ,but they didn't work.
Please help me out.
Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: What methods did you try, so that we don't waste time giving you answers you've already tried?

Comment: Take a look on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692947/get-parts-of-a-nsurl-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take your `NSURL` (or init one from the URL string), and use the method `pathComponents` which return an array of the words in the URL (separated from the slash `/`), so:

```
pathComponents[0] == @"photos.googleapis.com"
pathComponents[1] == @"data"
...etc.
```

Here the snippet of code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:@"https://photos.googleapis.com/data/upload/resumable/media/create-session/feed/api/user/111066158452258/albumid/60281009241807"];

NSString *user = url.pathComponents[9];
NSString *album = url.pathComponents[11];
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example here, [NSURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class is your friend. You can use e.g. `pathComponents`: to get an array of all components and then process this array as you need it:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://photos.googleapis.com/data/upload/resumable/media/create-session/feed/api/user/111066158452258/albumid/60281009241807"];
NSArray *components = [url pathComponents];
NSLog(@"path components: %@", components);  
NSLog(@"user: %@", components[9]);  
NSLog(@"albumid: %@", components[11]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://photos.googleapis.com/data/upload/resumable/media/create-session/feed/api/user/111066158452258/albumid/60281009241807"];
    NSArray *pathComponentsArray = [url pathComponents];
    NSString*userValue;
    NSString*albumidValue;
    for(int i=0;i<[pathComponentsArray count];i++)
    {
        if([pathComponentsArray[i] isEqualToString:@"user"])
        {
            userValue = pathComponentsArray[i+1];
        }

        if([pathComponentsArray[i] isEqualToString:@"albumid"])
        {
            albumidValue = pathComponentsArray[i+1];
        }
    }
```

Comment: sir i am trying this method and then let you know,thank you for your kind assistance.