# Remove all text after a symbol - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview, nsurl

I have a web view which encodes the string which is turned into url and when I check the url in the NSLog - this is the url.

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-30447248%23sa-ns_mchannel=rss&ns_source=PublicRSS20-sa%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20
```

I made this scanner below and I want to delete everything after the FIRST `%` so basically %23 is the first one I want to scan from % to the end of string.

```
 NSString *webString22222 = n2;



    NSScanner *stringScanner22222 = [NSScanner scannerWithString:webString22222];



    NSString *content22222 = [[NSString alloc] init];





    [stringScanner22222 scanUpToString:@"%" intoString:Nil];



    [stringScanner22222 scanUpToString:@"" intoString:&content22222];
```

Scanner I created, as you can see it has a percent sign for first `scanUpToString` then the second one I want some code which will indicate end of string like to be more precise something similar to this in real programming `scanUpToString:webString22222.endOfString` something to scan up to the end of the string and then delete it.

Sorry for not providing code earlier. Thanks.

Comment: You need to show us some code where you tried to solve this for yourself. It would also be useful to show what you would like the output to look like with your example.

Comment: I edited my whole question can you please look @rdelmar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3693009/1702413

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
Try this I hope it may help you.

 NSString *str1 = @"http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-30447248%23sa-ns_mchannel=rss&ns_source=PublicRSS20-sa%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20";
    NSRange range = [str1 rangeOfString:@"sa"];

    NSString *newString = [str1 substringToIndex:range.location];
    NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

Comment: Sorry it is static not always the same

Comment: @AjayVenkat, if you replace rangeOfString:@"sa" with rangeOfString:@"%", then this approach should work, and is simpler than using a scanner.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove this symbols you should simply try this:

```
[yourString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**Note:**

- I assumed you getting such URL on string, So i placed yourString as `NSString` variable.
- You can improve it as per requirement

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Sorry I really need that Enoding, or my app won't work

Comment: See my new question please.